# Rollback invalidated suggested edit

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, rollbacks

In the "suggested edits" queue I was presented with an edit to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42683496/8559300), which was manually undoing [this harmful edit to the question by the OP](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/42683496/2).

I rolled back the harmful edit, thinking this would make the post history cleaner, and then realised I'd cheated the edit proposer out of 2 rep.

Should I instead have accepted the proposed manual edit, or did I do the right thing?

Comment: The bigger question is: Why did the author of the question edit this unicode characters into the question?

Comment: @BDL true. I didn't ask that, because I suspect the answer is both unknown and unknowable. Although I am going through their posts to see if they did it anywhere else.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Up to you. There is nothing wrong with the rollback since it simply invalidated the suggested edit as opposed to rejecting it (which had one approve vote at the time you rolled back):

[image: timeline screenshot]

The author of the edit also did not get their suggestion rejected as well, so there is no harm done:

[image: screenshot of the relevant part of the edit author suggestion history]

That said, given that there isn't much else to fix about the post (other than maybe creating a better title), the suggested edit should've been probably approved to encourage good behavior (and rolling back self-vandalism evidently falls under this category) — just keep it in mind next time.